# Value can not be null exception while runtime in ternary operator in EF core 2.1 projection

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.2

Actually, I have issues with that I can not set null value instead of default value for the nullable field.

I can't write correct code with EF core 2.1 in the select statement because I faced with runtime exception "the value cannot be null" or it is impossible to use null propagation operator.

Note: if it is important, rows taken from sub-entity in the query.

```
VotedAt = i.CurrentUserVote == null 
    ? new DateTimeOffset() 
    : i.CurrentUserVote.VotedAt,
CurrentUserVote = i.CurrentUserVote == null 
    ? false 
    : i.CurrentUserVote.IsPositive,
```

I'd like to write:

```
VotedAt = i.CurrentUserVote == null 
    ? null 
    : i.CurrentUserVote.VotedAt,
CurrentUserVote = i.CurrentUserVote == null 
    ? null 
    : i.CurrentUserVote.IsPositive,
```

Or even:

```
VotedAt = i.CurrentUserVote?.VotedAt,
CurrentUserVote = i.CurrentUserVote?.IsPositive,
```

Other requested info by comunity:
Selected entity:

```
public class IssueListItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Votes Votes { get; set; }
}

public class Votes
{
    public int Positive { get; set; }
    public int Negative { get; set; }
    public int All { get; set; }
    public bool? CurrentUserVote { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? VotedAt { get; set; }
}
```

The select:

```
        return _unitOfWork.Issues.GetQuery()
                .Filter(query.Filter)
                .WithVotes<Issue, IssueVote, int>(currentUserId)
                .Order(query.Sorter)
                .Select(i => new IssueListItem
                {
                    Id = i.Item.Id,
                    Votes = i.Votes,
                    Title = i.Item.Title,
                    //removed some other properties
                })
                .ToListAsync();
```

where `WithVotes<Issue, IssueVote, int>(currentUserId)` is:

```
            return q
                .Select(i => new
                {
                    Item = i,
                    VoutesGroups = i.Votes
                        .GroupBy(v => v.IsPositive, v => true, (key, vg) => new { IsPositive = key, Count = vg.Count() }),
                    CurrentUserVote = currentUserId == null ? null : i.Votes.FirstOrDefault(v => v.CreatedById == currentUserId),
                })
                .Select(i => new AssignVotesModel<TEntity, TVote, TId>
                {
                    Item = i.Item,
                    Votes = new Votes
                    {
                        Positive = i.VoutesGroups.Where(vg => vg.IsPositive == true).Sum(vg => vg.Count),
                        Negative = i.VoutesGroups.Where(vg => vg.IsPositive == false).Sum(vg => vg.Count),
                        All = i.VoutesGroups.Sum(vg => vg.Count),
                        VotedAt = i.CurrentUserVote == null ? new DateTimeOffset() : i.CurrentUserVote.VotedAt,
                        CurrentUserVote = i.CurrentUserVote == null ? false : i.CurrentUserVote.IsPositive,
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

The defined column probably cannot be null in the database, Or in your entity Mapping.

Check that your Entity Model does not have `Required` attribute. Also check that specified Property is not tagged with `Required`  in `modelBuilder` configuration.

Lastly, check your Table Column from your RDBMS whether it is set as `IS NOT NULL`

Comment: I didn’t get wich entity should I check.
because
VotedAt and CurrentUserVote are fields to project to.
And i.CurrentUserVote is a calculated/joined field

Actually, I have issues with that I can not set null value instead of default value for the nullable field.